# Get duration AVPlayer link fade

Tags: avplayer

I am using the AVPlayer to play a live stream from the Internet, and I need to show the duration of the music file, but I can get duration because the link is fade and it change continuous in 5 minute. It always shows duration `NAN`.

This link is the end by `.mp3`:

http://www.yorkshireentertainment.co.uk/downloads/mp3-short/Pure%20VS%20mp3s/moon_river.mp3

It shows duration OK.

BUT this link doest NOT end with `.mp3`:

http://preprod-streaming-virgin.snowite.fr/plain/audio/full/128/GB/F07/65/20/010/GBF076520010_audio_full.mp3?st=lrmNZOXQTAszo46dNIiHGA&e=1348734612

I can NOT get the duration, it always shows `NAN`.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Could you provide an answer?